# Caption alignment in tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, tabularx

I want to take the caption of the table to right from left. Is it possible?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}
\newcommand{\myhdashline}{%
\addlinespace
\hdashline
\addlinespace}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}                                     
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}                                   
   {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection.}{0.5em}{}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=.15in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\footnotesize Financial Disclosure Index}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X}

\textbf{Caption} \\ \midrule \endfirsthead

\textbf{Caption} \\ \midrule \endhead \bottomrule \endfoot

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\textbf{Title} & \\hline

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

TextTextTextTextTextTextText&TextTextTextTextTextTextText\\myhdashline
TextTextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextTextTextText
\\myhdashline TextTextTextTextTextTextText &
TextTextTextTextTextTextText

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing [`longtable`](//ctan.org/pkg/longtable) notation with your use of [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)...

Comment: caption had not to be inside `tabularx` environment. exception is when you use `ltablex` package, but this is not evident from your document example.

Comment: sorry I forget to add packages I used. Yes, I installed ltablex.

Comment: @nebtune, please edit your question and add missing packages and explain your problem better. is your table with `tabularx` environment really so long that had to be broken over two or more pages?

Comment: @ Zarko I tried to add what you suggested. I hope it works. Sorry, I am not so familiar with these.

Comment: With `right to left`, do you mean a right to left language or just a right aligned caption?

Comment: @nebtune I think the ping will only work if you remove the space between @ and the name

Comment: @nebtune, meanwhile (before you edit your question) i upload answer on your question. please, inform me, if it solve your problem.

Comment: @samcarter the caption of the table shows on the top left side of the table. I want to take it to the top right side of the table.

Comment: @Zarko thank you very much for your effort but I can't say it solved. I just want to take caption which is "Table 1: My caption" to the top right of the table, not in the center or left side of the table.

Comment: @nebtune, sorry, this was not evident from your question ...

Comment: @nebtune Unrelated to your problem, but please don't load the same package multiple times.

Comment: @samcarter I generally copy-paste especially when it comes to packages in latex so that is why sometimes I just miss it and install a package more than one. But I will try to be careful about that. Thank you very much for answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are manually placing the caption within your tabular. If you want it to a) span the whole width and b) be right aligned, you could use a `\multicolumn`. Alternatively you could simply place a real caption outside the tabular.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headsep=.15in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X}

\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Caption}} \\ \midrule \endfirsthead

\textbf{Caption} \\ \midrule \endhead \bottomrule \endfoot

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\textbf{Title} & \\hline

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

TextTextTextTextTextTextText&TextTextTextTextTextTextText\\myhdashline
TextTextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextTextTextText
\\myhdashline TextTextTextTextTextTextText &
TextTextTextTextTextTextText

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]